# MVC Ajax.BeginForm and Content Security Policy

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

To prevent cross side scripting i implement CSP to one of my applications. At moment i´m reconfigure all html classes, so that javascript always comes from my server.

Now i found a page with an `Ajax.BeginForm` and always get the error "`Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".`" if i want to submit the form and update the view.

Can anybody help me, where the problem is?

Here is my html classes (shorted):

UserInformation.cshtml:

```
<div id="OpenAccountInformation">@Html.Action("OpenAccountInformation")</div>
</div>
```

AccountInformation.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bundles/ManageUsers/AccountInformation")
@model Tumormodelle.Models.ViewModels.AzaraUserModel

<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.Editable" id="EditableUserInformation">
<div id="Editable">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditUser", "ManageUsers", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "OpenAccountInformation", HttpMethod = "post", }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
        <div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "entryFieldLabel" })
            </div>
       </div>
          <div>
            <div>
                <button name="button" value="save" class="formbutton" id="saveButton">save</button>
                <button name="button" value="cancel" class="formbutton" id="cancelButton">cancel</button>
            </div>
                   }
</div>

<div id="NonEditable">

    <div>
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username, new { @class = "entryFieldLabel" })
        </div>
               </div>
           <div>
        <div>
            <button name="button" value="edit" class="formbutton" id="editButton" type="button">edit</button>
        </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

and the c# methods:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(AzaraUserModel AzaraUserModel, string button)
{
    if (button == Tumormodelle.Properties.Resources.Save)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            azaraUserManagement.Update(AzaraUserModel.Username, AzaraUserModel.Title, AzaraUserModel.FirstName, AzaraUserModel.LastName, AzaraUserModel.EMailAddress, null, AzaraUserModel.Phone, AzaraUserModel.UserID, (byte)AzaraUserModel.ShowMail.ID);
            ViewBag.Message = Tumormodelle.Properties.Resources.Personal_Data_Changed;
            ViewBag.Editable = true;
        }
        else ViewBag.Editable = false;
        BindShowMailList();
        return PartialView("AccountInformation", AzaraUserModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OpenAccountInformation", "ManageUsers");
    }
}

public ActionResult UserInformation()
{
    return View("UserInformation");
}

public PartialViewResult OpenAccountInformation()
{
    AzaraUserModel AzaraUserModel = new AzaraUserModel(azaraUserManagement.GetSingle(AzaraSession.Current.UserComparison.GetUser().Id));
    BindShowMailList();
    ViewBag.Editable = true;
    return PartialView("AccountInformation", AzaraUserModel);
}
```

Edit: With help of Chrome debugger i find out, that the error is thrown in the moment form becomes submited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ajax.BeginForm` will be generating inline script in the generated HTML of your page, which you have disallowed by use of `script-src 'self'` in your Content Security Policy.

If you want to use the CSP to prevent any inline injected scripts you must use `Html.BeginForm` instead and add the JavaScript to submit this via Ajax in an external `.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this attribute to your controller post action

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Comment: No that dont help :(. Checkt with the debugger of Visual Studio it seems that the c# class not even get hit as i click on the `save` button. On the other hand, the `cancel` button works fine, but don't need to call server.